# How to Remove Syntax In Source Editor

Tags: joomla-3.4

After entering the following code in joomla `<div id="bottom_fade"></div>` the following code automatically appears

> `<hr id="system-readmore" />`

. However, when I remove

> `<div id="bottom_fade"></div>`

the code `<hr id="system-readmore" />` remains.

Is there a way to prevent `<hr id="system-readmore" />` from being entered? I think its part of the system but not sure.

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Is this something that happened just once or keeps happening? Can you give more info? I mean, assuming you are using the editor and adding that did, it doesn't make any sense for that hr-readmore to be entered automatically... So more info on what exactly you are doing would help...

Comment: @FFrewin, it seems to appear after I add it with the DB Replacer. It seems to keep happening. The code looks like the following. <div id="bottom_fade">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="bottom_fade">&nbsp;</div>
<hr id="system-readmore" />
<div id="bottom_fade">&nbsp;</div> and the only way to get rid of it is to manually go into the source editor and delete it. I'm sure there is something occurring in the backend making it appear, but not sure what?

Comment: Can you show what you are doing with DB replacer? Can you confirm that anything you put in there to replace isn't creating this? AFAIK, Using DB replacer cannot trigger anything else - it will go and replace in the database whatever you instruct it... so make sure it's not your actions that produce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is from DB Replacer. It seems that it's adding a non-empty value to the fulltext field, and thus triggering the content model to add the `<hr id="system-readmore" />` code.

A non-empty fulltext is the only reason that can make Joomla automatically add the system-readmore code (of course, a non-core plugin can also do that, but that's a different issue).

Comment: that's probably a good explanation and a good catch. The OP might entering content in Full Text field, so the system hr- readmore is being generated.

Comment: Thanks @itoctopus. That was the reason and the resolution.